# How do I set MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in django-nonrel1.5 with mongodb engine?

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7

How do I set MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in django-nonrel1.5 with mongodb engine?

```
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 55, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Middleware module "%s" does not define a "%s" class' % (mw_module, mw_classname))
ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a version of Django prior to version 1.7 (1.6.4 to be specific), and SessionAuthenticationMiddleware was not introduced until Django 1.7. That's why the error is appearing.

Firstly define **INSTALLED_APPS** settings in your settings.py file.
After that, you should define MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.
Update your **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** settings in settings.py file,
Like this:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    )
```

Notice that you need to remove this line from your  **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** settings :

```
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
```

Comment: @jhonjhon123 Then show us the settings.py file of INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'chatterbot.ext.django_chatterbot',

    'example_app',
)

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    

        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

Comment: @jhonjhon123 updated my answer, please check now. Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: after removing 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', then same error at  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',.....i also remove this ....but now i am getting this error              ...........cannot import name JsonResponse

Comment: @jhonjhon123 Which version of Django are you using ?

Comment: django1.5  i am using....but i have already tried with  django 1.7...but django 1.7 gives the error at get table function...error this NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseIntrospection may require a get_table_list() method

Comment: @jhonjhon123 This error "cannot import name JsonResponse" is because you forgot to import JsonResponse as **from django.http import JsonResponse** somewhere in your files.

Comment: @jhonjhon123  I think my answer solved your current problem of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. If you have other question/problems in your code then you should post them as a new question with exact details.